# how can I use wget to download large files?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, wget

I'm using Linux Mint 15 Cinnamon running from an 8GB pendrive. I want to get the ISO for 'Linux Mint 14 “Nadia” KDE '. I tried using `wget` in the terminal. Here is exactly what I typed:

```
wget http://mirror.ufs.ac.za/linuxmint/stable/14/linuxmint-14-kde-dvd-64bit.iso
```

after it downloaded until 30% (after like 2 hours), I was dissappointed to see that it stopped downloading. I used `wget` because I do not want to leave my chromium-browser on. please help me so I can download it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you have an X-Y problem here. Don't download large files over HTTP if you have better options. rsync is better in this regard, since it can do file integrity checking. Not to mention that Linux ISO images are usually available over BitTorrent (unless you have to use one of those retarded ISPs that choose to block BitTorrent completely, to fight "copyright infringement").

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You [can continue failed downloads](http://fosswire.com/post/2007/09/quick-tip-recover-a-failed-download-using-wget/) using wget. (Provided where you're downloading from supports it)

*Quote:*

*Say we're downloading a big file*:

```
$ wget bigfile
```

And bang - our connection goes dead (you can simulate this by quitting with Ctrl-C if you like). Once we're back up and running and making sure you're in the same directory you were during the original download:

```
$ wget -c bigfile
```

Provided where you're downloading from supports it, you should get going from exactly where you left off.

Comment: +1, and yes, that server *does* support resuming (`Accept-Ranges: bytes; Content-Length: 1095761920`).

Answer (score 4):

Normally, `wget` has no file size limit.

If `wget` is failing, it is probably because you are running out of space on the pendrive. Do you have a free GB for the iso?

How did `wget` stop? Was there an error message? Did you perhaps allow the computer to go into suspend? If so, use `wget -c` as suggested by @dtmland.

Finally, `wget` does have an option to limit file size but it is not set by default. One possibility is that your sysadmin has set a limit by making `wget` an alias to something like `wget --max-filesize N`. To check if `wget` is an alias run `alias wget`. If it is, you can use `\wget` to bypass the alias and run `wget` directly.

Comment: Better yet, assuming you're not using csh or tcsh, `type -a wget`, which will also show you if it's defined as a shell function.